# Git clone with SSH in GitLab doesn't work

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have set my public SSH RSA key on my GitLab profile setting. And on my remote server I already added my SSH private key with:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

In fact, when I run SSH connection verification on my remote server it is authenticated:

```
user@some-remote-server:/var/www$ ssh -T git@gitlab.com
The authenticity of host 'gitlab.com (xxx.xx.xxx.xx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:anmsdaskdnaslkdmaskd.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab.com,xxx.xx.xxx.xx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
Welcome to GitLab, @alramdein!
user@some-remote-server:/var/www$
```

And I'm the *owner* of the repository. But when I ran Git clone it said `fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

```
user@some-remote-server:/var/www$ sudo git clone git@gitlab.com:repo/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
user@some-remote-server:/var/www$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `sudo git clone`; that means you aren't using the same `ssh-agent` as in your user.

If you want to check that, you can just perform

```
ssh-add -L
```

and

```
sudo ssh-add -L
```

And you will see that there isn't the same agent in both accounts.

I don't know why you want to do `git clone` with `sudo` rights, but then you'll need to start your agent with `sudo` (for the `root` user) and attach the private key to it.

Also, since `sudo` disables the environment variables, you'd have to provide the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and the `SSH_AGENT_PID` each time you use `ssh`.

Comment: my VPS provider does not allow me to use the root user. So I ended up changing the owner of the directory to my user. I find the answer earlier than this actually but thank you.

Comment: for those who seek the detailed solution, you can find it here https://mhagemann.medium.com/how-to-fix-ssh-permission-denied-with-git-clone-f669b65f90ac